# PARSING A COMPLEX XML USING DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I know that this sort of question has been asked here before, but still i couldn't find any solution to my problem. So please, can anyone help me with it.....

**Situation:**

I am parsing the following xml response using DOM parser.

```
<feed>
<post_id>16</post_id>
<user_id>68</user_id>
<restaurant_id>5</restaurant_id>
<dish_id>7</dish_id>
<post_img_id>14</post_img_id>
<rezing_post_id></rezing_post_id>
<price>8.30</price>
<review>very bad</review>
<rating>4.0</rating>
<latitude>22.299999000000</latitude>
<longitude>73.199997000000</longitude>
<near> Gujarat</near>
<posted>1340869702</posted>
<display_name>username</display_name>
<username>vivek</username>
<first_name>vivek</first_name>
<last_name>mitra</last_name>
<dish_name>Hash brows</dish_name>
<restaurant_name>Waffle House</restaurant_name>
<post_img>https://img1.yumzing.com/1000/9cab8fc91</post_img>
<post_comment_count>0</post_comment_count>
<post_like_count>0</post_like_count>
<post_rezing_count>0</post_rezing_count>
<comments>
<comment/>
</comments>
</feed>

<feed>
<post_id>8</post_id>
<user_id>13</user_id>
<restaurant_id>5</restaurant_id>
<dish_id>6</dish_id>
<post_img_id>7</post_img_id>
<rezing_post_id></rezing_post_id>
<price>3.50</price>
<review>This is cheesy!</review>
<rating>4.0</rating>
<latitude>42.187000000000</latitude>
<longitude>-88.346497000000</longitude>
<near>Lake in the Hills IL</near>
<posted>1340333509</posted>
<display_name>username</display_name>
<username>Nullivex</username>
<first_name>Bryan</first_name>
<last_name>Tong</last_name>
<dish_name>Hash Brows with Cheese</dish_name>
<restaurant_name>Waffle House</restaurant_name>
<post_img>https://img1.yumzing.com/1000/78e5c184fd3ae752f8665636381a8f0006762dc0</post_img>
<post_comment_count>6</post_comment_count>
<post_like_count>1</post_like_count>
<post_rezing_count>1</post_rezing_count>
<comments>
<comment>
<user_id>16</user_id>
<email>existentialism27@gmail.com</email>
<email_new></email_new>
<email_verification_code></email_verification_code>
<password>9d99ef4f72f9d2df968a75e058c78245fa45e9e7</password>
<password_reset_code></password_reset_code>
<salt>31a988badccd35a1be7dacc073f60f52e49ff881</salt>
<username>existentialism27</username>
<first_name>Daniel</first_name>
<last_name>Amaya</last_name>
<display_name>username</display_name>
<birth_month>10</birth_month>
<birth_day>5</birth_day>
<birth_year>1985</birth_year>
<city>Colorado Springs</city>
<state>CO</state>
<country>US</country>
<timezone>US/Mountain</timezone>
<last_seen>1338365509</last_seen>
<is_confirmed>1</is_confirmed>
<is_active>1</is_active>
<post_comment_id>9</post_comment_id>
<post_id>8</post_id>
<comment>this is a test comment!</comment>
<posted>1340334121</posted>
</comment>

<comment>
<user_id>16</user_id>
<email>existentialism27@gmail.com</email>
<email_new></email_new>
<email_verification_code></email_verification_code>
<password>9d99ef4f72f9d2df968a75e058c78245fa45e9e7</password>
<password_reset_code></password_reset_code>
<salt>31a988badccd35a1be7dacc073f60f52e49ff881</salt>
<username>existentialism27</username>
<first_name>Daniel</first_name>
<last_name>Amaya</last_name>
<display_name>username</display_name>
<birth_month>10</birth_month>
<birth_day>5</birth_day>
<birth_year>1985</birth_year>
<city>Colorado Springs</city>
<state>CO</state>
<country>US</country>
<timezone>US/Mountain</timezone>
<last_seen>1338365509</last_seen>
<is_confirmed>1</is_confirmed>
<is_active>1</is_active>
<post_comment_id>10</post_comment_id>
<post_id>8</post_id>
<comment>this is a test comment!</comment>
<posted>1340334128</posted>
</comment>
</comments>
</feed>
```

In the above xml response, i am **getting multiple "feed", which i am able to parse without any problem**, but here **each "feed" can have None or N numbers of "comment"**. I am **not able to parse the comment for an individual feed**. Can anyone suggest me how do proceed in the right direction.

I am **also putting a snippet of code here, NOT the entire code.. that i am using to parse the xml doc**, so it will be easier to pin point the problem.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory odbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder odb =  odbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document odoc = odb.parse(is);
odoc.getDocumentElement().normalize ();    
NodeList LOP = odoc.getElementsByTagName("feed");
System.out.println(LOP.getLength());

  for (int s=0 ; s<LOP.getLength() ; s++){

       Node FPN =LOP.item(s);
       try{
            if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {

            Element token = (Element)FPN;

            NodeList oNameList0 = token.getElementsByTagName("post_id");
            Element ZeroNameElement = (Element)oNameList0.item(0);
            NodeList textNList0 = ZeroNameElement.getChildNodes();

feed_post_id = Integer.parseInt(((Node)textNList0.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

 System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");
 System.out.println("post_id : " + ((Node)textNList0.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
 System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");

            }
           }catch(Exception ex){}
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the feed NodeList run on it and use:

```
NodeList nodes = feedNode.getChildNodes();

  for (Node node: nodes)
  {
    if(node.getNodeName().equals("comments")){
    //do something with comments node
  }
}
```